# Impossible to install Kivy for Python

Tags: python, installation, kivy

I don't understand why I can't install kivy.

I'm on Windows 10 64 bits with Python 3.10.

I have tried with `pip`, `pip3`, on administrator command, to install the `master.zip`.

Always the same error (and same with Python 3.9)

Here the terminal print:

```
<code>PS C:\Users\dieun\Desktop\Python\kivy> pip3 install kivy
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting kivy
  Using cached Kivy-2.0.0.tar.gz (23.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files\python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\dieun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-8ibcb9j6\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\dieun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-m3qb
6iun\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.24,<=0.29.21,!=0.27,!=0.27.2' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_dep
s.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew_dev~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew~=0.3.0; sys_platfor
m == "win32"'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (10 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-58.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (946 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.21,>=0.24
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1
    Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1 (from versions: 0.4.2, 0.
4.3)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1

  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/96/091ddacafb84dd18555a32d860dbfaf9c806147aa30c6f3c8b93cb7bab97/Kivy-2.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=d25e44eb44e43762b2fd0c5874e51954e0f1181fd9800d8a6756be6d084812d8 (from https://pypi
.org/simple/kivy/). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\dieun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-8ibcb9j6\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\U
sers\dieun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-m3qb6iun\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.24,<=0.29.21,!=0.27,!=0.27.2' 'kivy_deps.gstreame
r_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew_dev~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2~=0.3.1; sys_platform
 == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz (23.6 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error'''</code>
```

and again and again...

Comment: `Python 3.10` is very fresh version and not all modules are ready to work with this version. Authors may need time to recompile it for new Python. Better use `Python 3.9` or even `Python 3.8` and wait few months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the document about kivy https://kivy.org/doc/stable-1.10.1/installation/installation-windows.html

Kivy can be installed with one of the following python versions:

- Python 2.7, 32-bit
- Python 3.4, 32-bit
- Python 3.5, 32-bit
- Python 3.6, 32-bit
- Python 2.7, 64-bit
- Python 3.4, 64-bit
- Python 3.5, 64-bit
- Python 3.6, 64-bit

Comment: Thanks, i've try on Python 3.9 (last release) and the kivy example "Hello World" work